# Returning ::iterator from function does not compile

Tags: c++, templates, tuples

The following repo compiles fine:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

class Foo
{
public:

    typedef std::tuple<int, int> foo_type;

    std::vector<foo_type>::iterator Find() {
        return Listeners.begin();
    }

    std::vector<foo_type> Listeners;
};

int main() 
{
    Foo foo;

    auto i = foo.Find();
}
```

But when I template the tuple on P, Q as in the following repo, I get this error:

> syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Find'

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

template<typename P, typename Q>
class Foo
{
public:

    typedef std::tuple<P, Q> foo_type;

    std::vector<foo_type>::iterator Find() {
        return Listeners.begin();
    }

    std::vector<foo_type> Listeners;
};

int main()
{
    Foo<int, int> foo;

    auto i = foo.Find();
}
```

Comment: I think you're missing typename: `typedef typename std::tuple<P, Q> foo_type;`

Comment: Doesn't seem to make any difference.  Also why would I need to use "typename" there anyway?

Comment: @borg itym `typename std::vector<foo_type>::iterator`

Comment: @Yakk I wasn't sure if I should mark this as a duplicate or answer the question and link it. I guess that answers my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `typename` here:

```
typename std::vector<foo_type>::iterator Find() {
^^^^^^^^
    return Listeners.begin();
}
```

For a more detailed description, see [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/2069064)

Comment: OK but why do I need to use `typename' there?  Why isn't typedef enough?  It works btw, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Downvote? Also @Robinson, read the linked question and **fantastic** answer.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks Barry (no downvote from me!).